# from Calendar week to java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

With `java.time.ZonedDateTime` , you can get the calendar week( say week 1).

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

int getCalendarWeek(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime){
   int week = zonedDateTime.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
   return week;
}
```

**With year and a calendar week given (ex : 2019 and week 20 ) , how can you return a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` ?**

The first day ( Monday) of the calendar week is the date. Whatever hour.

```
ZonedDateTime getZonedDateTime(int year, int weekNumber){
// ???
}
```

Comment: You would have to use a predefined day, time and zone. That means that half of the fields in `ZonedDateTime` are fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `with` operation in the ZonedDateTime to obtain a date based on a specific week. The `WeekFields` class allows access to the `TemporalFields` required to do this. See the sample below:

```
int week = 1;
int year = 2016;
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.now()
                        .withYear(year)
                        .with(weekFields.weekOfYear(), week)
                        .with(weekFields.dayOfWeek(), 1);
```

Note that this does not solve the issue on the timezone, as it asumes the system default timezone.

Comment: I tried and got `2016-01-04T12:58:34.640077+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]`, which I suppose fulfills what is asked for. I would probably start from a `LocalDate`, apply the adjusters and at the end call `.atStartOfDay(desiredTimeZone)`. (Your variable name `ldt` tends to be misleading.)